# Empty string is...never empty

Tags: java, android

No matter what string test I use, I can never get my empty string to evaluate as true. In all cases, debugger says: *string: ""*, but it won't enter the if loop.   I've tried:

```
if (boolean isEmpty = TextUtils.isEmpty(kfl)) {  
if (string.isEmpty()) {
if (string == "") {
if (string.length() == 0) {
if (string.equals("")) {
if (string.equals(null)) {
if (string.equals("null")) {
```

What else could "" possibly mean?

Comment: It could contain an unprintable invisible character.  Print out `string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` and see what happens.

Comment: Post a minimal example which we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried the .getBytes idea and the debugger says {-17, -69, -65}. I guess that means there are 3 "invisible" bytes in that string? Is there a way to figure out what those are?

Answer (score 2):

It contains the byte order mark:

```
0xEF,0xBB,0xBF
```

You could try explicitly looking for the hex sequence.

Comment: I looked up "byte order mark" and am seeing the problem now. Notepad (where my string comes from) prepends the BOM when saving under UTF-8 encoding. I'll read further to figure out how to handle that. Thank you!

Comment: There are a lot of posts already on handling BOMs in Java. I won't bother adding all the links. I am sure you can find them.